# Cucumber and Jenkins: False "duplicate step definition"

Tags: java, jenkins, kotlin, cucumber

I'm getting this error message in a Jenkins build for a Java, Selenium and Cucumber project:

```
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.466 sec <<< FAILURE! - in 
e2e.CucumberTest
e2e.CucumberTest  Time elapsed: 1.466 sec  <<< ERROR!
cucumber.runtime.DuplicateStepDefinitionException: Duplicate step definitions in void  
e2e.sak.OpprettSakSteps.TestCaseDSLTester(String) in file:/tmp/workspace/n_DSL-og- 
TestsakBuilder_combined/e2e/cucumber/target/test-classes/ and 
e2e.sak.OpprettSakSteps.TestCaseDSLTester$default(OpprettSakSteps,String,int,Object) in file:/tmp
/workspace/n_DSL-og-TestsakBuilder_combined/e2e/cucumber/target/test-classes/
```

I don't see where the supposed duplicate step definition is? When looking through the Java/Kotlin file, there are absolutely no duplicates, and all step definitions have a trailing "$" (which has been the cause of earlier erroneous duplicate messages). Also, I don't understand what Jenkins is comparing, even though it seems that it tries to show me exactly where the duplicate is:

```
e2e.sak.OpprettSakSteps.TestCaseDSLTester(String)

and

e2e.sak.OpprettSakSteps.TestCaseDSLTester$default(OpprettSakSteps,String,int,Object)
```

It points to the same method, but with different parameters? Neither the method name nor the Cucumber step definition name is the same, so what's it complaining about?

Here's the step definition kode (Kotlin):

```
@Gitt("^jeg prøver meg på DSL for \"([^\"]*)\"$")
fun TestsakDSLTester(saksRef: String = "saken") {
    TestsakDSL.create {
        opprettet = LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(1)                                                                                                    
        kommunenr = "5035"                                                                                                              
        hovedsoker = "Kåre Kotlin"                                                                                                      
        fnr = "22097930922"                                                                                                             
        sokere = 2                                                                                                                      
        arbeidlisteHovedsoker { mutableListOf(mutableListOf("Knus og Knask AS", 100, true), 
        mutableListOf("Del og Hel", 20, false)) }
        arbeidlisteMedsoker { mutableListOf(mutableListOf("Kiosken på hjørnet", 50, false)) }                                          
        barn = 2                                                                                                                        
        biler = 1                                                                                                                       
        verger = mutableListOf(VergeUtils.Companion.VergeFor.HOVEDSOKER, 
                 VergeUtils.Companion.VergeFor.MEDSOKER)

    }

    System.out.println("");
}

@Gitt("en sak med (\\d+) søkere med hver sin verge$")
fun enSakMedNSokereMedHverSinVerge(): Testsak {
    return TestsakBuilder("saken",  "5035") 
           .setSoknadtype(Bakgrunn.Hva.values().toList().shuffled().first())
           .setVerger(vergeFor = 
             mutableListOf(VergeUtils.Companion.VergeFor.HOVEDSOKER)).createSak().build();
}
```

Comment: Looks like Cucumber doesn't ignore the synthetic `$default` method. Could you report this as a bug with https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm ?

Comment: Removing the default parameter value should solve the problem I think.